# Google CHARTS using json and $_GET and $_POST method

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, google-visualization

I need some help,I'm using google charts api but when I try to get some parameters using POST and GET it doesn't draw the chart.

How can I improve the code to achieve the task?

Thanks in advance

sql query:

```
SELECT answers,COUNT(*) as count FROM surveys
where company_area ='human resources' and date >= '2014-11-01' and 
date <= '2014-12-31'GROUP BY answers ORDER BY count DESC
```

**phpmyadmin's result after run the query.**

```
Answers   count(*)
YES         23
NO           1
```

**json output.**

```
 {"cols":
         [ {"label":"Answers",
            "type":"string"},{"label":"Answers","type":"number"}],
 "rows":[
         {"c":[{"v":"YES"},{"v":23}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"NO"},{"v":1}]
         }]}
```

**get_json.php**

```
  <?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error connecting to server');

mysql_select_db('sistema_encuestas', $con); 



$q = $_GET['q'];
$a = $_GET['a'];


// write your SQL query here (you may use parameters from $_GET or $_POST if you need them)
$query = mysql_query("SELECT areas_evaluacion.nombre_area, AVG(encuestas.respuestas) AS Promedio
FROM encuestas
INNER JOIN areas_evaluacion on areas_evaluacion.id = encuestas.id_area_evaluacion
WHERE encuestas.fechaentrevista>='".$q."' and encuestas.fechaentrevista<='".$a."'
Group by encuestas.id_area_evaluacion


");


$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'respuestas', 'type' => 'string'),

    array('label' => 'Respuestas', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['nombre_area']);
    //$temp[] = array('v' => (int)$r['id_area_evaluacion']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (float)$r['Promedio']); // typecast all numbers to the appropriate type (int or float) as needed - otherwise they are input as strings

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// return the JSON data
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

**chart.php**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">


         // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart(num,num2) {
                var json = $.ajax({
                    url: 'get_json_areas_por_dia.php', // make this url point to the data file
                    dataType: 'json',
                     data: "q="+num ,"a="+num2,
                    async: false

                }).responseText;

                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
                var options = {
                    title: 'Estadísticas por Áreas Por dia',
                    is3D: 'true',
                    width: 800,
                    height: 600
                };
                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                //do not forget to check ur div ID
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);


            }
        </script>

  </head>
  <body>


        <form>
        <input type="date" name="date1" onchange="drawChart(this.value)">
        <input type="date" name="date2" onchange="drawChart(this.value)">
  <select name="users" onchange="drawChart(this.value)">

  </form>

        <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help us answer you question better if you limited the code you posted to the relevant sections.  Also, are you getting any javascript errors or is it simply neglecting to make the chart?

Comment: it is simply neglecting to make the chart, It shows blank page

Comment: did you try larger interval looks like it make call every half second try every 10 seconds

Comment: 'get_json.php is missing '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the missing ' in the json url

**PHP**

```
echo ' {"cols":
         [ {"label":"Answers",
            "type":"string"},{"label":"Answers","type":"number"}],
 "rows":[
         {"c":[{"v":"YES"},{"v":23}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"NO"},{"v":1}]
         }]}';
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>      
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var json = $.ajax({
                    url: 'get_json.php', // make this url point to the data file
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    type: 'GET'
                }).responseText;

                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
                var options = {
                    title: 'My Weekly Plan',
                    is3D: 'true',
                    width: 800,
                    height: 600
                };
                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                //do not forget to check ur div ID
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);

                setInterval(drawChart, 500 );
            }
        </script>  
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes when you add the json output it shows the chart, but I want to get the data from a database and use $GET and $POST values to show the chart to the user. Is there a way to send the $POST directly to the index.html to draw the chart?

Comment: if you go directly to the PHP page what do you see?

Comment: yes when you add the json output it shows the chart, but I want to get the data from a database and use $GET and $POST values to show the chart to the user. Is there a way to send the $POST directly to the index.html to draw the chart?

Comment: try to compare the json output you get from get_json.php
to the json in my answer you must have identical structure

Comment: do you have this page online?

Comment: post goes from the index.html to your PHP script, are the index.html and the get_json.php in the same folder?

Comment: No I do not have it online yet, I compared the your json ouput and it is the same. Now the POST goes from another page which send the variable post to get_json.php, yes they are in the same folder,

Comment: if you wish to post some data you can add to the $.ajax data request object
it looks like data:{'param1':'value','parma2':'value'}
 and you will post it from the same page and not from other. I cannot help you any farther if I don't see it online.

Comment: I already uploaded it, you can see it online, here is the url androidft.comeze.com/google-charts , if you want to see the json output go to this androidft.comeze.com/google-charts/get_json.php?idCuest=9, I can send to your email, the files if you want to test it :) thanks

Comment: The json data is not the same as the data you posted, this is the problem. also you post the form data as string you should post it as JS object, data: {key:value}, For debuging I would remove the interval and use simple form, or atleast increase the time to 3 sec

Comment: see what I got now,  [http://androidft.comeze.com/google-charts/](http://androidft.comeze.com/google-charts/)  you can test it selecting or adding 16/01/2015 into the input box,  do you know how I can do to make a date range? I do not know how to send those two parameters

Comment: add the following to the $.ajax:
data:{'date':$('input[name="date"]').val()}
them you can catch the values in the PHP side via $_POST['date']

Comment: them you can catch the values in the PHP side via $_GET['date']

Comment: I tried to catch it using $.ajax: data:{'date':$('input[name="date"]').val()} but I couldn't do it , so I tried another way but I do not know how to catch two variables. I updated the question with my current code to make a date range, do you know how can I improve it to catch those parameters?